# Delete a table without doing a rollback-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I had a table from roles in the database. I created it using the command

```
php artisan make:model Role -m
```

**Problem:**

I deleted the table from the database with a rollback. So I deleted all of my tables from the database, deleted the create_roles_table.php from the migrations files and deleted the Role model and migrated all the remaining files again.

Now when I create a model with the same name as Role. The model is created but I get this error.

```
  [ErrorException]
  include(C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\vendor\composer/../../database/migrations/2018_09_20_061829_create_roles_table.php)
  : failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using a classmap configuration in your composer.json that involves the migrations. If that is the case, then rebuild it with `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Thank is alot. It worked for me